# adding external jsx file to an html page(react)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome

I have some react code in js/script.js
The head tag of my HTML page looks something like this:

```html
  <head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.6.2/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.6.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"type="text/jsx"></script>
    </head>
```

For some reason, my react elements aren't shown when I open the page on chrome, while they do in Firefox. I don't want to limit the page to Firefox and don't want to use inline script. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running a page directly from Chrome ( without http ), your page tries to run javascript and Chrome is blocking it with an error that looking something like:
"Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource”

You should install a web server and open your page by http request. 
command string: npm install http-server -g
and then run it by: http-sever 'path/with/yourpage.html'
your page should be accessible by URL: localhost:8080/yourpage.html